# Jquery on click not working after change event on selectmenu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, show-hide, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am trying to build a page in which list items are dynamically added under an "ul" element.

1. When a list item is clicked, it will open a selectmenu (jquery plugin)
2. User will select one of the values, after which the selectmenu needs to close(hide)
3. The selected value from menu is populated into text of list item which was clicked to popup the selectmenu.
4. After list item text is populated, dynamically add another list item underneath it
5. User should now be able to repeat from steps 1 to 4.

I am able to do the steps 1 to 4 first time but after selectmenu is hidden, clicks on newly added list item or any of the previously added listitems are not recognized.

I am not able to figure out, where all I am going wrong. Below is the html and jquery code. Any pointers will be appreciated

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="tree">
        <li class="connection" id="connection1">-------------</li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
<div class="selection">
    <select id="my-select" name="character" multiple="multiple">
        <optgroup label="The Griffins">
            <option value="Peter">Peter Griffin</option>
            <option value="Lois">Lois Griffin</option>
            <option value="Chris">Chris Griffin</option>
            <option value="Meg">Meg Griffin</option>
            <option value="Stewie">Stewie Griffin</option>
        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Peter's Friends">
            <option value="Cleveland">Cleveland Brown</option>
            <option value="Joe">Joe Swanson</option>
            <option value="Quagmire">Glenn Quagmire</option>
        </optgroup>

        <option value="Evil Monkey">Evil Monkey</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Javascript for the click function**

```
var i = 1;

$('body').on("click", ".connection", function () {
    var connectionid = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#my-select").selectmenu({
        change: function (event, data) {
            var selectedText = $(this).val();
            $("#connection" + i).text(selectedText);
            $(".selection").hide();
            i++;
            var id = "connection" + i;
            $("#" + connectionid).append("<li class='connection' id=" + id + ">-------------</li> ")
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer myself. "on" was not defined properly

```
$('.container').on('click', 'li',function (e) {
    //alert("hello");
    var connectionid = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".selection").show();
    $("#my-select").selectmenu({
        change: function(event,data){
            //alert("hello2");
            var selectedText = $(this).val();
            $("#connection" + i).text(selectedText);
            $(".selection").hide();
            i++;
            var id = "connection" + i;
            $("#" + connectionid).append("<li class='connection' id=" + id + ">-------------</li> ")
        }
    });

});
```